# What SQL syntax is this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

Can anyone tell me what SQL syntax this is please where 123 is the argument passed to the SP?

```
EXECUTE sp_MyStoredProcedure = '123'
```

When executing this command the error message from MSSMS is

> 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>    syntax near '='.

We need to configure the DB (SQL Server 2008 Express) to accept SQL of this syntax as it is generated by a windows service that we can't change. Trying to set the DB compatibility doesn't work...

```
ALTER DATABASE ABC SET Compatibility_Level = 80 / 90 / 100
EXECUTE sp_dbcmptlevel 'ABC', 80   --80,90, 100
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like a screwed up attempt to use the `@param=val` syntax; have you run a trace on this? Is it attempting to fetch parameters dynamically (e.g. `sp_sproc_columns`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax was invalid. The SQL in the windows service was obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [help topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), this syntax is just invalid and apparently never was valid for SQL Server. It looks nonsensical, too. Does it work for some other DBMS?

Comment: Yup, agree it looks nonsensical, but we're almost completely sure that it did work in a SQL Server environment. It's never been anywhere near another DBMS as far as we are aware

Answer (score 1):

```
EXECUTE sp_MyStoredProcedure '123'
```

Comment: You can also do EXECUTE sp_MyStoredProcedure @argumentName = '123'. We know what correct syntax should be, but can't figure out how the syntax in the OP worked